# How do I randomly display a set of backgrounds?

Tags: random, background, numbers, setting

I have five different backgrounds that I want to randomly display everytime the page reloads.  I'm still fairly new to java and not sure how to do this using R.drawable....

I was thinking I would have to generate a random number, use that number as part of a string and pass the string to the setBackgroundResource method, but that doesn't seem to fly.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.